# How to test single file upload controller with grails (without content-type= multipart/form-data)

Tags: unit-testing, testing, grails, controller, httprequest

How can one test a grails controller method which expects header `"Content-Type"` to be `"image/jpeg"` and a body with binary image data?

It seems `GrailsMockHttpServletRequest` is only usable for requests with binary data, if one uses multipart request, as the method `addFile` executes `setContentType("multipart/form-data")`and besides that there are only methods for handling json and xml bodys.

Comment: "It seems GrailsMockHttpServletRequest is only usable for requests with binary data" - That is not correct.

Comment: that is out of context – "…if one uses multipart request"  ^^.
And that is not the case as well (see answer) – but it seemed so to me ;)

Comment: "And that is not the case as well " - Agreed.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me… GrailsMockHttpServletRequest extends MockHttpServletRequest, wich has a `setContent(byte[] content)` method.